# i am displaying category,sub-category1 and sub-category2,my code is below

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i am displaying category,sub-category1 and sub-category2 ,for first category it will display sub-category1 and sub-category2 correctly.For others it will display sub-category1 correctly but  not subcategory2.

in my controller using this code

```
$this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->model('categories_model');
$data['categoryres'] = $this->categories_model->getCategories();
$this->load->view("home", $data);
```

my model page

```
 function getCategories()
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $query=$this->db->get('product_category');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $result =$query->result_array();

            for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
            {
                $query1=$this->db->query("select * from product_sub_category1 where category_id_fk='".$result[$i]['id']."'");
                if($query1->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                $result[$i]['sub1']=$query1->result_array();

                //$result1=$query1->result_array();
                for($j=0;$j<count($result);$j++)
                {
                  $query2=$this->db->query("select * from product_sub_category2 where sub_category1_id_fk='".$result[$j]['id']."'");
                if($query2->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                     $result[$j]['sub2']=$query2->result_array();
                }
                else
                {
                $result[$j]['sub2']=array();
                }
                }


                }
                else
                {
                $result[$i]['sub1']=array();
                }
            }

            //print_r($result);
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }

}
```

in my view using this code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs  hidden-xs" style="border-color: white;">
                <li class="dropdown ">
                               <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; color: #000000;text-decoration: none;background-color: #fff;"> 
                              <span style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"> Categories </i><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                <ul class=" amenu triangle-border top ">
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <?php for($a=0;$a<count($categoryres);$a++)
                                           { ?>
                    <li class="category" style=""><?php echo $categoryres[$a]['category_name'];?>


                                        <ul class="sub-menu"style="display: none; background-color: white;">
                                             <?php if(!empty($categoryres[$a]['sub1'])&& count($categoryres[$a]['sub1'])>0)
                                                   {
                                                 for($b=0;$b<count($categoryres[$a]['sub1']);$b++) {?>
                                                <li class="cat_head sub_category"><?php echo $categoryres[$a]['sub1'][$b]['sub_category_name'];?>
                                                    <ul class="sub-sub-menu"style="display: none; background-color: white;">
                                                        <?php if(!empty($categoryres[$b]['sub2']) && count($categoryres[$b]['sub2'])>0)
                                                   {
                                                        for($c=0;$c<count($categoryres[$b]['sub2']);$c++) {?>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $categoryres[$b]['sub2'][$c]['sub_category2_name'];?></a></li>

                                                   <?php } } ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>  
                                                   <?php }} ?>
                                        </ul>

                        </li>

<?php } ?>


                </ul>
                </ul>
                        </li>
            </ul>
```